# Skip adding a line break if next tag contains text in Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to prevent BeautifulSoup from adding a line break if the next tag contains the text "Utility".

```
<html>
    <dl>
        <dt>RandomText</dt>  <!-- Line Break -->
        <dt>RandomText</dt>  <!-- Don't insert Line Break -->
        <dt>Utility: NonStaticText</dt>  <!-- Line Break  -->
    </dl>
</html>
```

right now I have:

```
soup.unwrap('head')

for dt in soup.findAll('dt'):
    dt.insert_after('\n')
```

This is very minimal, but how would I go about this? The text "Utility:" occurs frequently, but the content after "Utility:" is different in every case, and is contained within the tag. I'm using BS4.

UPDATE:

I have found that:

```
for dt in soup.find_all('dt'):
    if not dt.find(string = re.compile('Utility')):
        dt.insert_before('\n')
```

seems to somewhat work. What I really need is to evaluate the next  tag in the tree and evaluate if it has the string 'Utility', and base my decision off that. Ideally ...

```
dt.insert_before('n')
```

should be:

```
dt.insert_after('n')
```

UPDATE 2:

This was the solution for me:

```
for dt in soup.find_all('dt'):
    next_tag = dt.find_next('dt')

    try:  # THROWS 'AttributeError' IF NOT FOUND ...
        if not next_tag.text.startswith('Utility'):
            dt.insert_after('\n')

    except AttributeError as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Take a look at the prettify function in Beautifulsoup4.

Comment: @WombatPM I did initially, but that doesn't mimic the format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the next tag with the [`find_next`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method, example:

```
for dt in soup.find_all('dt'):
    next_tag = dt.find_next()
    if not next_tag.text.startswith('Utility:'): 
        dt.insert_after('\n')
```

Note that if you dont pass any arguments in `find_next` it will match any tag that follows.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me get to a solution that worked perfectly.